# How to call a function from one script in another script?

Tags: powershell, integration-testing

I am writing an integration test and trying to get a function call from the prod script working in my test. Right now whenever I try to call a specific function it just runs the whole script instead.

In Integration.ps1 I have

```
. .\AddStart.ps1
Start -job $job
```

In AddStart.ps1 I have

```
function main()
{

Write-Host "This is Main"
Start($job)
}
function Start($job)
{

Write-Host "This is start $job"
}
Main
```

Whenever I run the integration in Powershell it outputs 
This is Main also.

I just want to pass the $job variable into Start without going into the main.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is explictly executing the `Main` function on the last line of the file. You could do something like this in AddStart.ps1...

```
Param([switch] $DontExecuteMainFunction);

function main()
{
    Write-Host "This is Main"
    Start($job)
}

function Start($job)
{

    Write-Host "This is start $job"
}

if(-not $DontExecuteMainFunction){
    Main
}
```

Then in Integration.ps1 dot source the file like this:

```
. .\AddStart.ps1 -DontExecuteMainFunction
Start($job)
```

If you exclude `-DontExecuteMainFunction` (such as your existing code) it reverts to its current behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Is your custom module in your $env:ModulePath directories or is it in a child directory of your script directory

Main script

```
Import-Module -Name .\ModuleTest
Test
```

Module Script in a directory called ModuleTest and a file called ModuleTest.psm1

```
Function Test { Write-Information -MessageData "My Test" -InformationAction Continue }
```

Also, what you are doing is dot sourcing your original script. And Start is an alias of Start-Job. Alias execute first before functions so that's an issue. Check this out:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the Main function at the end of the module. I removed it and called the function from PowerShell and it worked. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried saving the .ps1 as a .psm1 then importing that module, and then running the custom function?

Comment: I just tried that and when saving the .psm1 to my current directory then trying to call it from integration it says no module was found when doing Import-Module AddStart

Comment: Adding it to a module wont help. The `Main` function will be called when the module is loaded just like when dot sourcing the file.